# Dúvida sobre CI/CD para build e release de containers docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, integração-contínua, microsoft-azure

Estou construindo um pipeline de liberação de containers Docker no GitLab e no Azure DevOps. Porem me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Step do build:

```
docker build -f ./caminho_docker_file -t nome_minha_imagem .
docker tag nome_minha_imagem:latest url/nome_minha_imagem:latest
docker push url/nome_minha_imagem
```

Step da release:

```
 - aws ecs update-service 
 # apenas para pegar a ultima versão enviada e propagar nos containers
```

Com a configuração acima, funciona bem quando eu tenho apenas um build e em sequencia realizo a liberação da release.

O problema é quando eu tenho um build e demoro para fazer a release. E com isso outros builds podem ser disparados. Ou seja eu vou ter um build amarrado a uma release, porem quando a minha release é executada ela não ira propagar a imagem do meu build e sim do meu ultimo build não atrelado a release.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de por exemplo eu colocar a imagem no Docker gerada no meu build no ARTEFATO (e não enviar para cloud no momento do build) enviado para minha release, com isso vou ter a garantia que a minha release esta enviando a imagem do build correto.

Procurei na documentação e em alguns tutorias porem não encontrei, se alguém puder me explicar qual a melhor maneira e se tem como realizar isso agradeço.

Comment: no grosso modo, você precisa alterar seu processo de build e release para ao invés de dependerem da tag latest, você crie uma tag com a referencia desse build para posterior release.

Comment: Só pra entender, você roda o mesmo pipeline no Azure DevOps e no GitLab e envia para um registry na AWS? E seu ECS está configurado para usar esse Registry automaticamente com a tag latest?

Comment: Sim, isso que esta configurado